# Angular Firestore Collection Snapshot Changes

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using FireStore, I simply need to display the collection list data onto the component and next to each item that is displayed be able to delete the item.

I need to use SnapShotChanges() in order to get the ID for my delete method.

Here is my code. Nothing is console being console logged. I am on using Angular 7.

```
  userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  collection: any;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private adminService: AdminServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userCollection = this.afs.collection<any>('valuation');
    this.collection = this.userCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        actions.map(a => {
          console.log(a.payload.doc.data);
          console.log(a.payload.doc.id);
        })
      }
    ))
  }
```

Here is my template:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let o of collection | async">
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">
          {{o.address}}
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          {{o.name}}
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          {{o.email}}
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          {{o.phone}}
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <button mat-button color="warn" class="delete" type="button" (click)="delete(o)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: anything of interest on developer tools > network tab?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: The way that you are trying to console.log is kind of weird as it is a part of return objects. Can you try adding a tap operator right before the map operator instead e.g. `tap( (actions) => console.log('actions', actions));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `snapshotChanges` `AngularFirestore` gives you the Document as well as the `id` of the document.

You can then extract the actual value of the document using `payload.doc.data()` on the `action`.

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  collection: any;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userCollection = this.afs.collection<any>('valuation');
    this.collection = this.userCollection.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a => a.payload.doc.data()))
      );
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cloud-firestore?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: I have the a.payload.doc.data() printing in the console correctly now. But it is refusing to show up in the template with no errors.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('valuation');
    this.collection = this.userCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(a => {
        a.map(item => {
          return item.payload.doc.data();
        })
      })
    )

Comment: This : 

`ngOnInit() { this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('valuation'); this.collection = this.userCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe( map(a => { a.map(item => { return item.payload.doc.data(); }) }) )`

Should be 

`ngOnInit() { this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('valuation'); this.collection = this.userCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe( map(a => { return a.map(item => { return item.payload.doc.data(); }) }) )`

Either get rid of the `{ }` or place a `return`  for `a.map(...)` part

Comment: How is this supposed to work when you don't subscribe to the DocumentChangeAction observer?

Comment: I have tried the following but I am not receiving the changes:  ngOnInit() {
    this.messages = new Array<String>();
    this.afStore.collection<any>('messages').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            console.log('data is' + data +' id is' + id );
          });
      }
      )
)
  }