# is there is any possibility for getting data from particular id, data not showing

Tags: angular, view, crud, router

id also getting ,but in html file can't print data from a particular id,Actually am work with crud application.add,list,delete, was done, but in the case of view there is a problem about  onView function, can you please help me out

**view-ts-file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CrudServicesService } from '../services/crud-services.service';
    
@Component({
   selector: 'app-view-items',
   templateUrl: './view-items.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./view-items.component.css']
})

export class ViewItemsComponent implements OnInit {

   viewId: string | null
   viewItems: any
    
   constructor(private crudservice: CrudServicesService,
        private activatedroute: ActivatedRoute) {
    
   this.viewId = this.activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
        console.log(this.viewId)
   }
    
   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.onView()
   }
    
   onView() { 
       if (this.viewId !== null) {
          this.crudservice.viewFunction(this.viewId).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
            this.viewItems = data
          })
       }
   }
}
```

**html-file**

```
<ul *ngIf="viewItems">
     <li>{{viewItems?.item_name}}</li>
</ul>
```

service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CrudServicesService {
    
    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }
    
    viewFunction(id: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.db.collection('items').doc(id).snapshotChanges()
    }
    
}
```

**routing-file**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddItemsComponent } from './add-items/add-items.component';
import { ListItemsComponent } from './list-items/list-items.component';
import { ViewItemsComponent } from './view-items/view-items.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'view/:id', component: ViewItemsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is the routing file, these are fine, the problem is in the ts file, or service file also.

Comment: console.log(this.viewId) does it show view id?

Comment: yes Id also showing, but data not get

Answer (score 1):

So I assume `console.log(data)` in `onView()` doesn't show anything? If that's the case it might not even get to the service call itself because of `if (this.viewId !== null)`, `ngOnInit()` step happens only once in a component lifecycle.

I didn't work with AngularFirestore but you need to make some extra steps to get the data out of the `snapshotChanges()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304884/15440211